# dont work ...mapGetters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

> error [vuex] unknown getter: counter/count`

### structure:

#### store.js

```
const state = {
    someRootState: 'someRootState'
}

const getters = {
    getRootState: state => state.someRootState
}

import counter from './counter.js'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    modules:{
        counter
    }
})
```

#### counter.js

```
const state = {
    count: 10
}

const getters = {
    getCount: state => state.count
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters
}
```

#### App.vue

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

computed: {
    //doesn't work  [vuex] unknown getter: counter/count
    ...mapGetters("counter", [
        "count"
    ]),

    //doesn't work  [vuex] unknown getter: counter/count
    ...mapGetters({
        count: "counter/count"
    }),

    //work
    ...mapGetters(["getRootState"]),

    //work
    ...mapGetters({
        getRootState: "getRootState"
    }),

}
```

mapStates work's right, mapGetters dont work, please help me to understand

Comment: In what way are they not working. Please [edit] the question and add a description of what isn't working. Are you seeing the wrong results, no result, errors, or other useful clues?

Answer (score 5):

your getter is called `getCount`, not `count`, so the `mapGetters` call should look like this:

```
...mapGetters("counter", [
  "getCount"
]),
```